# Are inactive Profiles in Spring Boot included in jar file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to create multiple profiles. I want to create a testing, staging, and production profiles. For Staging I want to setup Engineered Data that will be loaded into a Embedded Hibernate Database so I can test my staging app based on preset staging data.

I was just curious about how this work when turning my final app into a jar file. When I finally do a `clean install` on my app, Will Inactive Profiles be include into my file. I am just concerned about the size of the app. I know it probably won't make any difference as far as memory usuage is concerned. But will it make my app bigger by using unused Configurations that fall under a inactive profile.

Answer (score 3):

The bean definitions are in the jar file but only beans in the active profile(s) are loaded into memory. So the jar will be a bit bigger, and Spring will have to skip over the inactive definitions, but that's all. Generally not worth worrying about.

Comment: You're right nothing to worry about. But what currently bothers me is following situation. Let's say you have an application and you want to have it running on different customers. Now let's asume everything stays and only your database settings differ and you control them by profile db_customer1 and db_customer2. Now I don't whant to rollout a piece software where customer1 can access customer2 db configuration and vice versa. Maybe this is only a leak of knowledge. What is your suggestion how to implement this?

Comment: Don't ask new questions on 4 year-old answers. This question was about beans not configuration properties. The solution to your problem is to externalize the properties outside of the jar and put the file on the class path; with a different file for each customer. If you don't understand what I mean ask a new question with more details.

Comment: Thx I'm fine with that anwser and you're right regarding new question!